# Index a nested list using X and Y values

Tags: python

I have a list of vertices and the length between them. I want to create a function which finds the distance between 2 vertices in the list by searching through the list.

the list will look something like:

```
lengths = [[X, Y, length], [X, Z, length], [Y, Z, length], etc]
```

Say the vertices are X and Y could I index the list using X,Y to find the length between X and Y?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
def find_sides(X, Y, lengths):
    for a in lengths:
        if a[0] == X and a[1] == Y:
            length = a[2]
    return length
```

But as the list of lengths grows this could take time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary:

```
lengths = {(X, Y): length, (X, Z): length, (Y, Z): length, ...}
```

Then it's just a matter of indexing the dictionary:

```
length = lengths[(X, Y)]
```

You can transform your current list to the proposed format with a dictionary comprehension:

```
lengthDict = {(a, b): c for [a, b, c] in lengthList}
```

Comment: +1. but if the matrix is not sparse, nested lists - `lengths=[[length1, ..], ..]` might be better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - however the list is automatically populated from values read into it, it's not sure how easy creating a dictionary is compared to creating a nested list

Comment: The dictionary seems right, but be careful about the type of X and Y.  If they are already in an exact type that should be fine, but if they are floating-point then you should round them before doing the lookup.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how to transform your current list.